# Is there way to determine the path that was picked from java.library.path?

Tags: java, c, windows, java-native-interface

I encountered an interesting problem:

An error "UnsatisfiedLinkError" with the message "The specified procedure could not be found"

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Test\TestJNI.dll: The specified procedure could not be found`

Whilst the JNI dll was happily being detected, it turns out that an incorrect version of a dependent dll was also being attempted to be loaded from a different directory in the library search path, triggering the above error message.

So my question is: Short of checking all directories for the presence of this incorrect version of a dll, is there a way to determine which directory the dll was attempting to be loaded from?

Comment: programmatically? probably not. But you can use dependencies.exe or dependency walker to simulate the loading for yourself.

Comment: On Windows you can run Sysinternals ProcessMonitor and check which DLL files the Java process accesses after the command to load TestJNI.dll was executed.

Comment: Thanks @Robert, ProcessMonitor was something that I considered. I was hoping there would be a way to enable a more verbose output during the load library process that may have revealed the paths being picked.

Comment: The problem is that to my knowledge loading the dependent libraries is performed automatically by the WinAPI function LoadLibrary, thus on Java interpreter level I don't think you will see the loading process. The only way to bypass this automatism would be to manually load the correct dependent dll file (e.g. via `System.load`/`System.loadLibrary` ) before loading TestJNI.dll.